# Will interest rates on bank deposits ever fall close to 0 percent in India?

Tags: india, retirement, savings, interest-rate, pension

I wanted to know if interest rates will ever fall to close to 0 percent in India.
+ I would like to know that as close to 0 interest rates might affect the income earned through debt instruments at retirement age. Resources which show interest rate history of the central bank will be helpful?
+ How does one secure oneself from if this event really happens.  Diversification into real estate could be one idea.
+ What else can be done other than that to ensure steady income even in falling interest scenarios ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to know if interest rates will ever fall to close to 0 percent in India.

This can't be predicted. India is a developing country and it would still be quite sometime to reach a developed nation that typically has near 0% rates.

> How does one secure oneself from if this event really happens. Diversification into real estate could be one idea.

Diversification is a good idea with or without rates going to 0%.